# Blender (2.8) won't retain child/parent relationships when linking / duplicating between scenes

Tags: parent, linked-data, scene

Is there some sort of trick to make Blender retain the child/parent relationships between objects when you link/copy them between scenes?

It seems Blender destroys them. Is there a reason why Blender does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to select both the *Parent and the children*, so the relationship is kept.

[image]

But Blender also remembers the relationship, so you can move parented items one by one.

[image]

It works reliably in the Outliner (Collections and Scenes) and also simple copy/paste in the 3D Viewport.